# Chrome Android 6x version input value replace duplicate value

Tags: android, jquery, google-chrome

This problem happened with my phone (Samsung Galaxy Note 4)

I am using jQuery, I am trying to code such that if a person fill (keyup jquery) value on input, text will spilt into 4 digit number

> example : 123412341234 will become 1234-1234-1234

but when i test my code
example : **123412341234**

it become

```
1234-1123-4121-2341-2312-3412-3412-3412-3411-2341-2341-2123-4123-4123-1234-1234-1234
```

below is my code :

```
$('#account_bank_number').keyup(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var account_bank_number = $(this).val();
  var account_bank_number_filter = account_bank_number.replace(/-/g, "");
  var account_bank_number_new = autoSplit(5, account_bank_number_filter, '-');
  $('.debug-mode').html(account_bank_number_new);
}

function autoSplit(number, string, splitChar) {
  var stringLength = string.length;
  var countNumber = 1;
  var newString = '';

  for (var i = 0; i <stringLength ; i++) {
    if (countNumber == number && string.charAt(i) != splitChar) {
        newString = newString+splitChar+string.charAt(i);
        countNumber = 2;
        continue;
    } 
    newString = newString + string.charAt(i);
    countNumber++;
  };
return newString;
```

}

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Hi no sure if you need this but you can do a simple :

```
var str = "123412341234";
str.replace(/(.{4})/g,"$1-").slice(0,-1);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 //uncomment if you want do it onload page
 //$( "#account_bank_number" ).keyup();
});

//test on click to the input
$( "#account_bank_number" ).click(function() {
  $( "#account_bank_number" ).keyup(); //this is a trigger
});

$('#account_bank_number').keyup(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var account_bank_number = $(this).val();
var account_bank_number_filter = account_bank_number.replace(/-/g, "");//no sure you need it ...
var account_bank_number_new = account_bank_number_filter.replace(/(.{4})/g,"$1-").slice(0,-1);
$('.debug-mode').html(account_bank_number_new);
//adding the value to the input comment if you dont need 
this.value = account_bank_number_new;
});
```

```css
.debug-mode{background-color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="account_bank_number" type="text" value="1234123412341234"/>
<div class="debug-mode"></div>
```

Simple regex "." is the string.  "{4}" is the number to cut the string every 4 characters. "$1-" is the pattern. "$1" is the new string cutting and the "-" at this end is the character being added and the slice is for deleting the last characters added by your replace function. Regards

Comment: replace str to the $(this).val(); "this.value" inside your event or  using document.getElementById or document.querySelector('input[name="class_name"]) for example, regard

Comment: i did a change, you can take a look, regards.

Comment: thank for help me but it not work if u use keyup jquery event bro

Comment: i need change input value when i keypress or keyup event